# How do I modify an existing git submodule to track a branch instead of a commit, and vice-versa?

Tags: git, git-submodules

When you add a submodule to your project using the traditional `git submodule add https://example.com/someproject.git` form, git ties your project to a specific commit in the subjproject. Initially, it's whatever commit was master at the time you used the command, then it's whatever you explicitly check out.

For a while now, git has had support for submodules to track the tip of a branch. I can add such a submodule with the syntax `git submodule add -b somebranch https://example.com/someproject.git`. This adds branch-related info in git, and you can see this in .gitmodule. I can do `git submodule update --remote` from a project to update the submodule to the latest commit in the chosen branch (somebranch in the example above).

Currently I have two projects which use the same submodule added via the traditional form.

1. I'm working on a new major change, and would like to temporarily switch to the branch tracking. So I'm working in the parent projects in branches called newfeature. I'm also making frequent changes to the submodule's sub-newfeature branch. I'd like the parent project's newfeature branch to always be using the latest commit from the submodule's sub-newfeature branch. How do I do this?
2. When I'm done in a month or so, I'd like to undo the change from #1. So remove the branch tracking, and go back to traditional submodule behavior. How would I do this?

Comment: Note that this stored branch name is only used when you (*manually*, i.e., *you*, not Git itself) invoke `git submodule update --remote`. So Git really only has submodules tied to a specific commit: you have to manually tie them to a new specific commit, to get any sort of update in place. So the answer to #1 is: "you do it yourself anyway, so just do it when you want to do it." The answer to #2 is: "there's nothing to put back."

Comment: I thought git was doing more behind the scenes, because .gitmodules shows this extra line that isn't there in traditional submodules: ```branch = somebranch```. Due to how painful it is to fully remove a submodule, I thought maybe this feature also had its tentacles deep into internals. 

So when I'm done I can just edit .gitmodules to remove the line? Also, based on what you said, how do I specify which branch should be used to update on ```update --remote```? Manual editing of .gitmodules?

Comment: You can manually edit the `.gitmodules` file, yes, or you can add an override in `.git/config`. The `.git/config` setting is favored, if both exist. There is at least one ongoing project to improve submodule handling to have an "on branch all the time" mode like you're thinking about, but it has not gone anywhere in more than a year, I think.

Comment: Is there some convenient workflow I'm missing with submodules? Should people in my situation really be making a commit in the parent project every time they make a commit in the submodule and want to start using it? I do this a few times a day.

Comment: You only (only?!) need to make a commit in the superproject when you mean to "announce", as it were, that the superproject should now use that particular submodule commit-hash-ID. That could indeed be several times a day. The superproject Git won't update the submodule Git unless you tell it to do so (with `git submodule update` or the recursion options) so if your workflow involves making a bunch of "trial commits", as it were, in the submodule, you can do that and then replace them with the final "good, do use this" commit and *then* add-and-commit in the superproject.

Comment: Overall, though, the "user experience" for submodules is ... not good. (Hence the nickname, "sob-modules")